# Getting `class must either be declared abstract scala` with sealed trait

Tags: scala

I'm reading through docs and trying to understand what Scala traits and objects and all these fun things are, but still unable to figure out how to resolve this problem.

```
sealed trait MyTrait {
  val username: Option[String]
  val password: Option[String]
}

sealed trait OptionTrait{
  val types: Option[Types]
}

case class Types(
  col: String
)

case class MyTraitTypes(
  user: String
  password: String
)

case class MyClass (
  auth: Option[MyTraitTypes]
  type: Option[Types]
) extends AnotherClass with OptionTrait with MyTrait
```

The error is on `MyClass`, where it wants `Class must either be declared abstract or implement abstract member password: Option[String]` in MyTrait`. Any help please?

-----edit

so my confusion is that `OptionTrait` works just fine. I can't distinguish the difference between these two (the working one vs non-working one). Because it doesn't seem like that `class Types` is doing anything either.

Comment: In your example, `MyClass` extends `MyTrait` which means `MyClass` needs to implement all the abstract methods, also your `MyClass` signature looks weird, it is taking `Option[MyTrait]` as a constructor parameter and it also extends `MyTrait`. Do you really want that?

Comment: no idea - I'm still figuring out these traits and stuff. Should I be creating another case class to put in place of `Option[AnotherCaseClass]`?

Comment: @abkf12 Only you can know that. Depends on your logic.

Answer (score 0):

There should not be comma after `username`. Also `auth` should be in parentheses rather than braces.

Try

```
class AnotherClass

sealed trait MyTrait {
  val username: Option[String]
  val password: Option[String]
}

case class MyClass(
  auth: Option[MyTrait]
) extends AnotherClass with MyTrait {
  override val username: Option[String] = ???
  override val password: Option[String] = ???
}
```

where you are supposed to implement methods instead of `???`

Comment: The comma and {} were already caught in IntellilJ anyway. I'm unable to do actually do the override part. It looks like this file just has a bunch of config objects with case classes and sealed traits so it was suggested to not do have any override functions here.

Comment: @abkf12 Feel free to ask when you have some specific question. Now it's not clear what your problem is.

Comment: sorry - not my logic so it's hard to explain everything going on here. I do see some sealed trait with def vs val (no functionality though, it just says either `def something: String`. What are the differences in usage of these two in terms of sealed trait?

Comment: I added more code and also a specific question. Thank you for your patience!

Comment: @abkf12 The difference between `OptionTrait` and `MyClass` is that the former is a trait and the latter is a class. Traits (and abstract classes) can have abstract members (without implementation), classes can't. One can't instantiate trait (or abstract class) but can instantiate class (create instance of this class), and for this instance implementations of all members must be known. That's the reason why classes (not abstract) must have members implemented. You should read about traits, classes etc. https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/classes.html https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/traits.html

Comment: edited the code again - so the question is more like.. why does type in MyClass work fine when auth doesn't? What's breaking about auth? And none of these are implemented (like how java has override function for implementation.. I'm looking through the project but can't find the actual implementation)

Comment: @abkf12 `type` is a keyword in Scala, so you can't use it as a field name. But you can write `type` in backticks and then it's a legal field name. I guess you're wrong, both `auth` and `type` work ok for `MyClass` (they are constructor parameters), the trouble is with `types`, `username`, `password` that they are not implemented.

Comment: `type` is just something that I gave for this example - I think I figured it out! I made it so that `MyTrait` has one member `MyField` and this is a `Option[MyClassTypes]` and the `val username, password` are now all moved to `case class MyClassType`